# Chauchy theorem in the particular case of a first order separable variables differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question on the particular case of the Cauchy theorem for a first order  differential equation with separable variables.

$y'(x)=a(x)b(y(x))$

If I impose:

$a(x)$ continuous in a interval $I$

$b(y(x))$ continuous and with continuous derivative in a interval $J$

Can I say that there is only one solution in **all** the interval $I$ that satisfies the condition of passage through a point $(x_0,y_0) \in I \times J$?

Or, instead of the continuity of the derivative of $b(y(x))$, should I impose that the derivative of $b(y(x))$ is limited on $J$?

Can anyone suggest me the correct conditions to impose in this particular case?

Thanks in adivce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions ensure local existence and uniqueness. However, there is no condition that forces the solution to stay inside the interval $J$.

As a classical if overused example take $y'=y^2$ which falls in your class. Solutions blow up in finite time, so you get all, solutions leaving $J$, and solutions not existing on the whole of $I$.

Comment: Thanks! Neither $J=\mathbb{R}$ would be a condition for the solution to stay inside all $I$? (I assume that in your first sentence you mean $I$ instead of $J$). With "your conditions" you mean the continuity of $b(y(x))$ or the fact that it is bounded?

Comment: No, $y(I)\subset J$ resp. its negation was intended. With $J=\Bbb R$ you still have the possible blowup in finite time. Which can be avoided by a global Lipschitz constant or the direction of the vector field at the boundaries of $I×J$. But still it shows that a general claim without further conditions is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I'm asking again but, at least,  what's a sufficient condition to impose for local uniqueness, among the ones that I listed (continuity or limitation of the derivative of $b(y(x))$)?